# NetCDF in QGIS --constructing time series using 1368 bands

Tags: qgis, netcdf, zonal-statistics, loop, batch

I have the NetCDF file that contains monthly gridded temperature from 1900 to 2014 ([air.mon.mean.v501.nc](https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.UDel_AirT_Precip.html)). The goal is to extract monthly time series for every polygon in my shapefile. Using the [US county map](https://www.qgistutorials.com/downloads/tl_2013_us_county.zip) as an example, the resulting shapefile should contain (2014-1900)x12 = 1368 columns, with every row containing the monthly average temperature for a given county for the period between 1900 and 2014.

My departing point was the use and abuse of a combination of Zonal Statistics and the Batch Processing function in QGIS. However, it seems that I have to manually select 1368 bands when specifying the raster layer for every row.

Is there a more time-efficient (and less prone to human error) way to do deal with the issue in question?

Comment: This should be possible to do using some scripting, but also, my immideate gut feeling when someone mentiones a table with 1368 columns is that this is not a good data model.... Are you going to do any kind of time series of the extracted data, if so, have you thought about how to get the data out?

Comment: @MortenSickel Thanks for your quick response. Well, if it is hard to pull 1368 columns out of QGIS, I will be happy to export multiple csv tables with, let's say, 50 columns per each. The goal is to construct a panel dataset, where panelvar is a polygon, and timevar -- month-year.

Comment: THe number of columns should not be any problem for QGIS, I was thinking more generally, it may just work fine for your application

Comment: I recommend you to use R packages to perform this process. If you are interested I can post an answer using R.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example using R. I used `raster`, `rgdal`, and `exactextractr` packages. However you can adapt the code and use much modern packages such as `terra` and `sf`.

```
# Input patches
# @IMG_PATH: absolute path of your RasterStack containing 1900 a 2014 monthly composites
# @SHP_PATH: ESRI Shapefile of EEUU
IMG_PATH <- "D:/Image.nc"
SHP_PATH <- "D:/Roi.shp"

# Read data
imgCube <- raster::stack(IMG_PATH)
shpFeatures <- rgdal::readOGR(SHP_PATH)

# Extract mean values by ROI
df <- exact_extract(imgCube, shpFeatures, 'mean')

# Export extracted data (optional) to csv
out_path <- "D:/Extracted.csv"
write.csv(df, out_path)
```